# how do display static background text in a sortable div?

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have two sortable div with divs inside as sortable element.

I would like the first one to display a bakground text such as "drag an image here".

The point is that when a draggable div is dragged on the first sortable div, the background text moves to give place to the incoming  div. My question is how to have this background text static ?

Comment: Maybe share some code or a jsfiddle or where you are so far?

Comment: You could make an actual background image; that is, a graphic saying "drag an image here". For extra points, make it an SVG.

Comment: I founded a way to do it, instead of putting the text inside the sortable div, I put it outside with absolute position and z-index...